# HTML JavaScript querySelector to find an element whose child has a specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

In my below HTML markup, I'd like to query the `<div>` that has a `data-parent` set to "true", and the contained child has `data-child-gender` set to "true" and inner html is "male".

```html
    <div id="grandparent">
      <div id="parent1" data-parent="true">
        <div id="child1" data-child-gender="false">
          male
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="parent2" data-parent="true">
        <div id="child2" data-child-gender="true">
          female
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="parent3" data-parent="false">
        <div id="child3" data-child-gender="true">
          female
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="parent4" data-parent="true">
        <div id="child4" data-child-gender="true">
          male
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Given the above scenario, the expected `<div>` is **parent4**.

What is the JavaScript querySelector to use?

Comment: You can’t use `querySelector` to find text content. There will be a manual check involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `querySelectorAll` which will give an array. Then iterate over it and check and get element with required `data` attribute.

After that you can use use a `if` & check the content inside it

```js
let k = document.querySelectorAll('[ data-parent=true]').forEach(function(item) {
  let elem = item.querySelector('[data-child-gender=true]');
  if (elem !== null && elem.innerHTML.trim() === 'male') {
    console.log(item.id)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div id="parent1" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child1" data-child-gender="false">
      male
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent2" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child2" data-child-gender="true">
      female
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3" data-parent="false">
    <div id="child3" data-child-gender="true">
      female
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent4" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child4" data-child-gender="true">
      male
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one `querySelector` you can use for this (as you can't use it to select specific text within elements). However, you can use `.querySelector()` with `.filter()` to get more specific results:

```js
const true_children = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-parent='true'] [data-child-gender='true']")];
const res = true_children.filter(({innerHTML:g}) => g.trim() === "male");

console.log(res);
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div id="parent1" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child1" data-child-gender="false">
      male
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent2" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child2" data-child-gender="true">
      female
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3" data-parent="false">
    <div id="child3" data-child-gender="true">
      female
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent4" data-parent="true">
    <div id="child4" data-child-gender="true">
      male
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the question describes, cannot be solved using query-selectors alone. This is because of following reasons:

1. The query selectors always works on descendants, so while evaluating that the child div has `data-child-gender="true"`, there will be no way to return the parent element. The query-selector will return the child div.
2. There is no way to evaluate the inner text or contained text of an element in query-selector.

These two limitations can be worked around by using JavaScript, provided that you were going to use the query-selector in JS.

Something like the following snippet should work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-parent=true] div[data-child-gender=true]')
.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.innerText === 'male'; // filter the elements containing male string.
})[0].parentElement; // return the parent of matched element.
```

An equivalent logic could be derived for selenium too. Otherwise if this much logic is unacceptable, you can always use the much richer `xpath` selectors. `xpath` wouldn't have either of the limitations mentioned above.